# Norminette empty line or not at end

Tags: vim

Why people on VStudio with [norminette](https://github.com/42School/norminette) highlights put an empty line at end.
And when they do norminette in iTerm it’s Works

When you use Vim and put an empty line at end the norminette say Error extra line.

This happen yesterday and today my Vstdio ask for a line at end and when I do norminette in iTerm it’s say error extra line. I go back to vim, delete the line and norminette say error again to remove extra line. I need to open back the file, add line and then delete and save to have norminette working. So now sometime moulinette say KO on server but OK my side. I need to add/remove last line every time with vim when I work on vstdio

So if someone know the issue i would like to have a better solution than double check on vim for the next 3 week and maybe 3 years  thx all!

Comment: I don't know what norminette is, but this sounds like the difference between DOS text files (which treats a newline as a line *delimiter*) and Unix text files (which treats a newline as a line *terminator*). That is, DOS text files do not end with a CR/LF pair, while Unix text files end with a LF.

Comment: Don't you have tutors at 42 for those questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That topic has already been discussed to death.

No matter what system you are on, lines in text files generally end with one or two invisible characters. On some systems, it's a "carriage return" `CR` followed by a "line feed" `LF`, on other systems it's only a `CR`, on other systems it's only a `LF`, and that's only for the least exotic ones. That character or pair of characters has a few colloquial names: "newline", "EOL", etc. I  will use "EOL" from now on.

Now, EOL has two semantic interpretations. In some contexts, EOL is considered to be a "line terminator", meaning that no assumption is made about what comes after it, and in some other contexts, EOL is considered to be a "line separator", meaning that there is always a line after it.

And then there is the related problem of how a stream of text should end. With the first interpretation, the last line of a stream should end with EOL, if only to be able to establish a boundary between two streams. With the second interpretation above, the last line of a stream shouldn't end with EOL because it would mean… that the last line is not really the last line.

So, basically, this text:

```
foo
bar
baz
```

could be encoded as (first interpretation):

```
foo<EOL>
bar<EOL>
baz<EOL>
```

or as (second interpretation):

```
foo<EOL>
bar<EOL>
baz
```

Most Unix-like tools have adopted the first interpretation for decades and generally expect EOL on the last line but many more modern tools have adopted the second interpretation, which leads to much confusion among new generations who juggle between GUI editors and CLI tools.

Feed some text with a final EOL to a tool that interprets it as a "line separator" and you get an imaginary line displayed at the end of the file:

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 baz
4
```

Feed some text without a final EOL to a tool that interprets it as "line terminator" and you can get anything from a reasonable display (as follows) to loud complaints (git):

```
1 foo
2 bar
3 baz
```

Add to that confusing names like "newline" and you have a recipe for a never-ending stream of questions like this one.

So… this is what seems to be going on, here:

1. you are using a mix of tools that interpret EOL differently,
2. you are interpreting one of those interpretations incorrectly,
3. and you act upon that misinterpretation, with confusing results.

Let's address these one-by-one.

1. Well, we all do so `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`.
2. What appears like an extra line at the bottom of your file in a modern GUI editor is unlikely to be an extra line. It is more likely to be an artefact of the second interpretation. Assuming you are on some kind of Unix-like system and the expected EOL is `LF`, you can do `$ xxd filename` to inspect its content in hexadecimal form:

   - a single `a0` at the end means that your file ends with EOL,
   - a `a0a0` at the end means that your file has an extra empty line,
   - no `a0` at the end means that it was written by a an editor that firmly adheres to the second interpretation.

   The second case will angry your linter:

   ```
   Error: EMPTY_LINE_EOF       (line:   7, col:   1):   Empty line at end of file
   ```

   but it doesn't seem to particularly care about the other two cases.
3. Because you see what appears to be an empty line at the end of a file in a GUI editor it doesn't mean that a) that line actually exists and b) that you must add one at the end of the file in Vim or any other editor.

   The correct approach is to:

   - let Vim do what it does out the box, write files with an EOL at the end, because that's what your toolchain (including Norminette) expects,
   - set up your GUI editors to do the same (even if they still show that imaginary line),
   - get rid of any extraneous empty line you might have in one of your projects,
   - NEVER add an extraneous empty line at the end of your files, as it useless at best and forbidden at worst.